# How to lookup for unique records using AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've a requirement where there are duplicate values available in a DE.
I've tried **LookupOrderedRows()** however, it gives all the records from the DE.

is there any way i can remove duplicate values & retain only unique records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to de-duplicate ahead of time with a Query Activity and then just do a simple looking in your email:

```
select
  x.emailaddress
, x.accountType
from (
  select
    de1.emailaddress
  , de1.accountType
  , row_number() over(partition by de1.emailaddress order by de1.accountType) rowNum
  from DataExtension1 de1
) x
where x.rowNum = 1
```

This groups the rows in the Data Extension by EmailAddress and then numbers the rows for each AccountType.  The `x.RowNum  = 1` picks the first AccountType per EmailAddress.

Or your can just de-duplicate ordered rows with AMPScript based on the primary key of your Data Extension -- `ProductName` in this example:

```
%%[
var @i, @rows, @row, @productName, @prevProductName, @rowsToReturn

set @rowsToReturn = 0 /* up to 2000 */

set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("SubscriberProducts" ,@rowsToReturn, "ProductName asc", "EmailAddress",emailaddr)

set @prevProductName = ""

for @i = 1 TO RowCount(@rows) DO

  set @row = Row(@rows,@i)
  set @ProductName = Field(@row, "ProductName")

  if empty(@prevProductName) or @productName != @prevProductName then

     set @prevProductName = @productName

]%%

     <h1>%%=v(@productName)=%%</h1>

%%[ endif ]%%

%%[ next @i ]%%
```

Comment: Is it possible to apply some sort of dedupe logic if no primary key is used?

Comment: The de-dupe logic is handled in the query in this line: `row_number() over(partition by de1.emailaddress order by de1.accountType) rownum`  Translation: assign a number for each unique email address ordering them 1-N for each account type ascending.  The where clause limits it to only the 1's for each email address.